# .htaccess redirect .html to non .html not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

using this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the site is displaying a 404 Not Found, even though I have the file.

The file is ishared.html. The redirect works, but it takes to a not found, if you go to http://headupshouldersback.com/ishared.html

Any tips? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The following gave me 500 server error on my site:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: So you want `/ishared` to show you the contents of `/ishared.html` ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

After your redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Add to the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?page=$1.html [QSA,L]
```

It is going to work. This will show the contents of `ishared.html` if you do the request for `ishared`.

EDIT:

It got into a loop, sorry, you need to use some php code.

index.php:

```
<?php file_get_contents( (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : "error.html"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it caused my whole site to have a 500 server error. I edited my top message with the new code I had, with your suggestion.