# .htaccess file [GETTING 500 ERROR]

Tags: .htaccess

Anyone to tell me the error with the code ? i'm getting 500 error!

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

### EDIT:

- I would like remove .php extension

Thanks

Comment: Why would you tag it as [tag:javascript]?

Comment: What does this code need to do? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

First, write the `RewriteEngine ON` at the top, use `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` for the whole. After some `RewriteCond` comes one `RewriteRule`.

After this, it is probably going to work.

EDIT: (as the question edited)

Here is the answer, it just answered: [Remove HTML extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294308/htaccess-redirect-html-to-non-html-not-working/24296522#24296522)

Comment: <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>